# missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'

Tags: python

Trying to make a checkers game with pygame. I want to call a function draw_board in my Board class to draw the board but I get the error.

> TypeError: draw_board() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'

Main.py

```
import pygame
from checkers.constants import HEIGHT, WIDTH
from checkers.board import Board


FPS = 60

Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Checkers')

def main():    
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print("click")

        Board.draw_Board(Screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        
    pygame.quit()

main()
```

board.py

```
import pygame
from .constants import RED, BLACK, COLS, ROWS, TILE_SIZE

class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        self.selected_piece = None
        self.red_left = self.white = 12
        self.red_kings = self.white_kings = 0
    
    def draw_board(self, screen):
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(row % 2, ROWS, 2):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (row * TILE_SIZE, col * TILE_SIZE))
```

Comment: You have to call `draw_board` from an *instance* of `Board`, not from the class itself.  e.g. `board = Board(); board.draw_board(screen)`

Comment: `draw_board` is an instance method and you didn't pass the instance you want to operate on. You forgot to actually create an object of the `Board` class...

Comment: You lack the basics. Read about [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) and [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) .

Comment: Thank you, everyone and I will give both the links a read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not provide accurate code: you do not call `draw_board` anywhere in the posted code.  However, you do have *this* line; the capitalization may be a typo:

```
    Board.draw_Board(Screen)
```

I think you have confused calling instance methods vs class methods.  You have tried to call an instance method through the class.  `Board.draw_board` is calling it through the class, which means that you have to give both arguments inside parentheses.  Your code supplies only one.

The intended way to call `draw_board` is as an instance method, such as

```
game_board = Board()
game_board.draw_board(Screen)
```